# Display first and last half of any string entered into textbox

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I want to display the first and last characters of any given string entered into a textbox. The strings can be of any length as the user wants (as long as it is one word) I would like to be able to do something like this... "william = will and iam" or "Celtic = Cel and tic"

I understand I would have to split or divide the string. How would I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks for your help once again guys, this is how the code ended up!

```
Dim strInput = txtString.Text

    Dim halflength = strInput.Length / 2
    Dim firsthalf = strInput.Substring(0, halflength)
    Dim secondhalf = strInput.Substring(halflength)

    Dim strResults = firsthalf
    Dim secondResult = secondhalf


    MessageBox.Show(firsthalf)
    MessageBox.Show(secondhalf)

    MessageBox.Show("First half of string contains... " & " " & strResults.Length.ToString & " characters", "Character Count")
    MessageBox.Show("Second half of string contains... " & " " & secondResult.Length.ToString & " characters", "Character Count")
```

**EDIT**:

Also meant to mention my current incorrect code.

```
Dim strInput As String
Dim strLength As String
Dim strResults As String
strInput = txtString.Text
strLength = strInput.Length / 2
strResults = txtString.Text
MessageBox.Show(strInput.Length.ToString, "Length of characters")
MessageBox.Show(strLength.ToString)
MessageBox.Show(strResults.Substring(0, 3))
```

Comment: Homework help?  Have you even thought about it at all.  Seems very simplistic and straightforward

Comment: Also meant to mention my current incorrect code. 

Dim strInput As String
Dim strLength As String
Dim strResults As String

strInput = txtString.Text
strLength = strInput.Length / 2
strResults = txtString.Text

 MessageBox.Show(strInput.Length.ToString, "Length of characters")
 MessageBox.Show(strLength.ToString)
 MessageBox.Show(strResults.Substring(0, 3))

Comment: Do you have to split it two evenly sized strings or two strings with even number of vowels?

Comment: @Lirik preferably split it into an even number of vowels. For instance "William would be Will and Iam, whereas a name like "Steven" would be "ste and ven".

Comment: @wilbomc If I get it correctly, then you're trying to do something more complex: tepid is split into "te" and "pid", tougher is split into tough-er, singer is sing-er. There are [some rules/guides](http://www.annies-annex.com/syllabication_rules.htm) on how to do this, but it's fairly complex... so do you have any more concrete requirements for those cases? What about aeiou?

Comment: @Lirik Not at the moment as it was something I was just messing around with, I'm happy with the responses. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [`String.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) should give you everything you need to get started on this.

Seeing your existing code will make this easier. Let's walk through what we have now.

Let's assume we have just a plain, simple string like this instead of a textbox for the sake of making things easier:

```
Dim txtString = "Hello World"
```

Now, in order to split the length of the string in half; we need to get the length. The `Length property will give is that, and then divide it by two.

```
Dim halfLength = txtString.Length \ 2
```

This will perform [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html); so any remaining decimal is truncated.

Now we know where the middle of the string is. We can now use `String.Substring` to carve out a peice of the string by index. `Substring` takes two parameters, the index where to start the string, and number of characters to take. There is a second overload that takes the index to start at and consumes till the end of the string. Indexes are zero based. So for example, if we wanted to start at the beginning of the string, we'd use zero. If we wanted to skip the first character, we'd use one.

For the first half of the string, we don't want to skip any characters, so we'll use zero. The number of characters we want is half length of the string, so we pass in `halfLength`:

```
    Dim firstHalf = txtString.Substring(0, halfLength)
```

For the second half, we want to start in the middle of the string, and consume characters till the end, so we'll use the other overload:

```
    Dim secondHalf = txtString.Substring(halfLength)
```

You now have your string split in half.

The final result looks like this:

```
Dim txtString = "Hello World"
Dim halfLength = txtString.Length \ 2
Dim firstHalf = txtString.Substring(0, halfLength)
Dim secondHalf = txtString.Substring(halfLength)
```

Comment: Thank you. Currently looking into it. I can get the length but can only display first and last characters according to how I assign it i.e first half, string.substring(0, 3) but the problem is dealing with the unpredictability of someone entering a larger string.

Comment: Fantastic post. Also thanks for explaining it as I'm still a beginner level programmer! Thank you!

Comment: Wrong, that won't perform integer division. The integer division operator in VB.NET is the backslash, \. I don't believe this code will compile under `Option Strict On`. Also, no ending semicolon :)

Comment: What's more, it uses bankers' rounding. This leads to some [incorrect results](http://ideone.com/K8LQA).

Comment: @minitech Hey! Took in what you were saying and made some changes. Used Cint to do the conversion so now it runs with Option Strict On. May I ask what you mean by bankers rounding producing incorrect results though? Quite curious. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @wilbomc: It'll round up to the nearest 2, not 1. `CInt(1.5)` = 2 but `CInt(0.5)` = 0. See the demo I linked to. You can fix this using `Math.Ceiling`.

Comment: @wilbomc I opted against `Math.Ceiling` and used integer division. It depends on what you need if the string is an odd number of characters. If the second half should be "favored"; then integer division is fine. If the second half should be favored; like in your "william" example, use Ceiling.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the rules are "each side is half the length with the left side taking precedence", you would use `Substring` and some simple division:

```
Dim str As String = "william"
Dim part1 As String = str.Substring(0, CInt(Math.Ceiling(str.Length / 2.0#)))
Dim part2 As String = str.Substring(part1.Length)

part1 & " and " & part2 'will and iam
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/J69Av)

Answer (score 0):

My code displays first half and last half of any number of characters entered.

1. Declare Variable

   ```
   Dim strResults As String
   ```
2. Fetch text from textbox

   ```
   strResults = Textbox1.Text
   ```
3. Display the first half of the text

   ```
   MessageBox.Show(strResults.Substring(0, strResults.Length / 2), "First Half Characters")
   ```
4. Display the last half of the text

   ```
   MessageBox.Show(strResults.Substring(strResults.Length / 2), "Last Half Characters")
   ```

Full code:

```
    Dim strResults As String
    strResults = Textbox1.Text
    MessageBox.Show(strResults.Substring(0, strResults.Length / 2), "First Half Characters")
    MessageBox.Show(strResults.Substring(strResults.Length / 2), "Last Half Characters")
```